# Is seeking immortality a sin in islam?

Tags: sin

Perhaps a scientist who combines machine technology with human life to achieve an immortal life?
Is that haram?

Answer (score 2):

The Quran in Surah Ali Imran states

> كُلُّ نَفۡسٍ ذَآئِقَةُ الۡمَوۡتِ​ؕ وَاِنَّمَا تُوَفَّوۡنَ
>   اُجُوۡرَكُمۡ يَوۡمَ الۡقِيٰمَةِ​ؕ فَمَنۡ زُحۡزِحَ عَنِ النَّارِ
>   وَاُدۡخِلَ الۡجَـنَّةَ فَقَدۡ فَازَ​ؕ وَمَا الۡحَيٰوةُ الدُّنۡيَاۤ
>   اِلَّا مَتَاعُ الۡغُرُوۡرِ‏
>
> ***Every soul will taste death,*** and you will only be given your [full] compensation on the Day of Resurrection. So he who is drawn
>   away from the Fire and admitted to Paradise has attained [his desire].
>   And what is the life of this world except the enjoyment of delusion.
>   [**(3:185)**](https://quran.com/3/185)

If you analyze the first part of the ayah, you will realize that Allah has revealed every soul in this world will experience death. Thus immortality is something He has reserved for the Hereafter.

But whether it is a sin to pursue immortality  or not depends on whether you believe or deny that ayah in the Quran.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Even if that happens in the end when universe dies we shall follow it. Death is most patient one.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're asking Allah for a thing you KNOW that He won't do, and hence it might be provocation or disrespect. So better avoid these questions.

Answer (score 0):

no we can't every soul and human should have a taste of death and death is the most pain ful  thing but we shall have death and raise again at the day of judement we may go jannah may allah for give our sin .. I hope I answeredyour question brother or sister

Answer (score 0):

Immortality is impossible by all the laws of physics. Entropy invariably increases. This is consonant with Islam. Hence it is haram. What is not haram is to help humans live well - and which is the general aim of medical ethics.

Answer (score 0):

There's something here you're missing. Your soul will leave your body one day no matter what. So if we assume that a genius has managed to forge machine technology with our bodies, your body becomes literally a humanoid. Your BODY will continue to work normally and wake up everyday for work and continue daily routine. But it's empty of soul, thus becoming literally a humanoid, a functional body, functional brain, functional heart, but no soul, you're the soul.